# Reference to a C structure in C++

Tags: c++, c, reference

I need to use some C defined structures in my  C++ code. Below is the structure in a C header file

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct TestParameters {
    long     p1;
    long     p2;
    long     p3;
} TestParameters_t;
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
```

Below code compiles but is the behavior defined and valid as per standard to receive C instance as reference and use it?

```
TestParameters_t testParams;
test(testParams);

// Is it valid to receive a C struct instance as a reference in C++ code
void test(TestParameters_t &testParams)
{

}
```

Comment: I don't see why this should be a problem.

Comment: @AlexFarber: No, it affects linkage. Name mangling is probably the most visible aspect of linkage, but calling conventions could be affected as well.

Comment: @MSalters, In C structures cannot have member functions and the concept of linkage is only applied to identifiers denoting objects and functions. So, `extern "C"` has no effect on `TestParameters` (though it might, if there were pointers to functions involved).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, even if the structure comes from a C header file you can use it as you would do with a structure defined in a C++ header file.

It's better to pass structures using its reference or its address than using its value.

Just don't forget to mark it as ***const*** if the function won't modify it.

```
void test( const TestParameters_t &testParams)
{
  // Won't modify testParams;
}
```

or

```
void test( TestParameters_t &testParams)
{
  // Will modify testParams;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as you use `test` only in C++ code, using reference is not only allowed, but recommended way to pass the parameter.

As an example of illegal usage, you could try to cast it to `void (*)(TestParameters_t*)` and pass this pointer as callback to some C code - this is illegal and invokes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this will work fine in C++.

In general C is a subset of C++, but there are exceptions to that. Normal `struct` definition and usage is not one of those exceptions.

Wikipedia does a good job of completely listing the exceptions though: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C%2B%2B#Constructs_valid_in_C_but_not_in_C.2B.2B

I would second [A.G.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1479549/a-g)'s point about passing `const` references, when you are writing C++.

---

I presume you know that `extern "C"` prevents the name mangling that C++ does, so that anything defined in that `extern` scope can also be used by C? If you're only planning to use that `struct` **only** in C++ code. I'd recommend removing all the `extern` stuff. Also note that you no longer need the `typedef` or the suffix name if you're just in C++.

In C++ you can define your `struct` like this:

```
struct TestParameters {
    long     p1;
    long     p2;
    long     p3;
};
```

And subsequently use it as simply: `TestParameters`.

But **only** do that if you're removing C support.

Comment: Note the conditional `__cplusplus`. This code is still meant to compile as C, so the `typedef` is absolutely needed.

Comment: @MSalters Yeah I agree, but since the calling code uses a reference, that's clearly C++ only. My thought was that if the OP was just moving code to a C++ only environment this might be beneficial. I've edited to clarify.

Comment: @MSalters This is generated code using some open source libraries. We have no plan to convert it to C++ structs

Comment: @Sirish Ah, very good ignore everything below the horizontal rule then.